# task.js generators/promises vs. async callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I want to know which of the two methods are better when dealing with asynchronous code in JavaScript. I want to understand which method leads to cleaner code. I'm used with promises and they seem more flexible than the async approach (https://github.com/caolan/async).

I also know about the Task.js library (http://taskjs.org/), but this relies on the yield keyword which is part of Ecmascript Harmony.

Comment: The main advantage of using the async library linked is that it *wraps/provides* a number of common operations in an async style. While "plain" [Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) (i.e. jQuery.Deferred) can be used, it would take much more boilerplate (if one of those operations is desired in an async style) as you'd effectively have to write your own versions of said functions. The async library linked and Promises ultimately work the same way - a *callback* is used.

Comment: What I like about promises is that you return something from a function, instead accepting a callback which you will call later (for me it's like saying: I can't return this value to you in this moment, but I promise you that you will get a value). What I don't like is that you have to pass 2 functions, but this will be resolved when EcmaScript Harmony will be ready. Given the fact that Task.js is so awesome, promises are really future proof. Maybe it will be interesting to develop a module that closes the gap between promises and callbacks (something like async, but returning a promise).

Answer (score 11):

The `async` library encapsulates a couple of very common asynchronous patterns, including making arbitrary async calls in parallel and iterating over a list asynchronously. It's designed to work with "nodeback" `(err, res)` APIs, which makes it useful for a lot of Node.js applications. `async` is however a *specific* solution, and it only simplifies the async patterns included in the library.

Promises, by contrast, are in my opinion a much more *general* solution to the problem of asynchronous code. Not only do they provide the obvious benefits at first glance of error-bubbling and of flattening callback pyramids, problems that would otherwise require the sorts of complex patterns `async` encapsulates can be solved much more simply.

I'll demonstrate this with a quick tour through some of `async`'s available patterns. For instance, the `async.waterfall` function is used something like this:

```
async.waterfall([
      function (cb) {
        asyncCall('argument', cb);
      },
      function(resultOfFirstCall, cb) {
        anotherCall(resultOfFirstCall, 'someOtherArgument' cb);
      },
    ], function(err, res) {
      if (err) handle(err);
      useFinalResult(res);
    });
```

There's no equivalent to `async.waterfall` in most promise libraries (or at least there isn't one in Q), because it's *so simple* to implement it from scratch using `Array.reduce`, like so (example based on Q but pretty much the same on other promise libraries):

```
[
  function() {
    return asyncCall('argument');
  },
  function(resultOfFirstCall) {
    return anotherCall(resultOfFirstCall, 'someOtherArgument');
  }
].reduce(Q.when, Q())
 .then(useFinalResult, handle);
```

The other big functions in `async` include `async.parallel`, which Q includes as `Q.all`:

```
// async
async.parallel([
    asyncFunc,
    asyncFunc2
    ], function(err, res) {
      if (err) handle(err);
      useFinalResult(res);
      // res[0] === asyncFuncResult
      // res[1] === asyncFunc2Result
    });
// Q
Q.all([
  asyncFunc(),
  asyncFunc2()
]).then(useFinalResult, handle);
```

And `async.map`. You actually *don't need* `async.map` when you're using promises, because the normal `Array.map` is sufficient:

```
// async
async.map(['file', 'file2', 'file3'], fs.stat, function(err, res) {
  if (err) handle(err);
  useFinalResult(res);
});
// Q
Q.all(['file', 'file2', 'file3']
  .map(Q.nfbind(fs.stat)))
  .then(useFinalResult, handle);
```

The rest of `async` is similarly easy to implement concisely, using relatively simple pieces of your promise library. (Note that that last example used a function `Q.nfbind`: `nfbind` and the other `nf*` functions Q provides are basically all you need to use promises with nodeback APIs, so there isn't even a particularly big impedance trying to use promises with libraries that expect nodebacks.)

In the end, whether you use promises or nodebacks is up to you, but I think promises are a much more flexible, capable, and generally concise way to implement most all asynchronous operations.

[Callbacks are imperative, promises are functional](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2013/03/30/callbacks-are-imperative-promises-are-functional-nodes-biggest-missed-opportunity/) is worth a read for more information in this general vein.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged your question with node, I'd recommend the async library. The control flow functions are great to work with and eliminate the ugly and hard to follow callback chains. The API is setup really nice for injecting callbacks that follow node's signature `(error, result)` into the control functions.  It's basically included by default in almost all node scripts I write.

While you can use async for client-side as well, it's probably unnecessary for most projects. jQuery includes promises, and you can accomplish the same thing with them.

Answer (score 1):

I think promise/a and async lib with difference targets, promise focus on one step async operation progress, and async focus on multi step async operate, for node, async has a wilder use for a lot of async apis.

by the way, to deal with async operations, use named function instead of Anonymous functions will be the most effective way

Answer (score 0):

gumballhead recommended **async.js**, but *i* would recommend using [**Parse Cloud Code**](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide) if you're working with Node. Their API has promises built right in, along with other goodies (like a database). It saves time and you don't have to worry about backend stability. You can include any NPM module with a little tweak of `module.exports` to just `exports`. It also integrates seamlessly with your frontend! I've been having success with this approach on my current project and just wanted to comment with a new approach.

Feel free to comment with any reasons why/when you should **not** use Cloud Code; for I have had no such experience yet.